# Can one use 5A transistor for motor driver of BLDC motor 920kv?

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing an esc for 920kv motors. For Code testing purposes on microcontroller, I want to make a low speed circuit but only have TIP122 (5A transistor) available in hand. Can they handle ESC control of EMAX 920kv. I will be using 3s battery to power the motor.

Comment: They can handle the voltage. As long as you don't over-do it on the current it might work. But I think it would be easier to get MOSFET's and follow some reference design for driving a BLDC with MOSFET's.

Comment: Motor Kv doesn't really matter to this question.

Comment: More than the voltage you should check the rated current of your motors.

Comment: It may be that as a professional, I have a totally different attitude than you. For me, I can get a wide variety of transistors from mouser.com or digikey.com in two days. The shipping cost will be 8-11 USD at the moment. It will take me longer than that to design and order the circuit board and write the code. So I would just pick good transistors, design the circuit, order the boards, and order the transistors at the same time. No problem. The fact that I have some ancient Darlington power transistors on hand would not really influence my decision. Your situation may be different.

Comment: From what I tested, they can handle the load if I keep the rpm low with no load. But I totally don't recommend it since starting current is high and if I am not careful with the rpm then transistors may burn (They were already getting very hot if I kept it running for more than a minute). Thank you for the help and I will get some Mosfets. P.S. Motor rating was 30A and its risky so don't try it at all.

Comment: I'm the only one who initially read that as 920 kilovolt motors?:D

Comment: I would be the first person to try to run a 920kilovolt motor with 3s lipo battery :|

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio the terminology is kind of unfortunate. Also a lot of people capitalize incorrectly making it even more confusing. Kv is a motor constant. The voltage constant that tells you how many RPM you get per volt. And kV is kilovolt. Ideally nobody should use KV or kv because who knows that that is? LOL.